# How to configure css flexbox so height of one of the block depends on it content?

Tags: css, layout, frontend, flexbox

I try to use flexbox to achieve next:

1. footer and header with fixed height.
2. editor get all space witch don't get attachments
3. attachments height from 0 to 148px depending on content (attachments number)

Is that real? I only have achieved proportional resizing of .attachments/.editor blocks with flex-shrink / flex-grow without content dependency.

http://jsfiddle.net/7ADtq/

HTML

```
<section class="page">
    <header></header>
    <section class="editor"></section>
    <section class="attachments">
        <article></article>
        <article></article>
        <article></article>
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.page{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;

    background-color: #f00;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.page header{
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;

    background-color: #0f0;

    margin: 0 0 10px 20px;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ebeced;

}

.page footer{
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;

    background-color: #00f;

    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 0;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-top:1px solid #ebeced;   
}

.attachments{
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;

    background-color: #0ff;

    max-height: 148px;

    margin: 0 20px; 
    outline: none;
    color:#3c434a;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 25px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.attachments article{
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid #e3e4e6;
      background-color: #fff;
      height: 57px;
      width: 303px;
      margin: 10px 10px 0 0; 
      position: relative;
      line-height: 57px;
}

.editor{
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;

    background-color: #ff0;

    margin: 0 20px;
    position: relative; 

    outline: none;
    color:#3c434a;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

Господа, я хочу что бы у меня с помощью флекбоксов блок с редакторов заполнял все место, которое не заполняет блок с аттачментами, и что бы блок с аттачментами был высотой от 0 до 148px в зависимости от наличия в нем аттачментов. 
Подскажите, это вообще реально? 
Если я пробую применить flex-shrink / flex-grow оно просто пропорцианально заполняет пространство блоками, без учета контента внутри.

http://jsfiddle.net/7ADtq/

Comment: whats that written below?

Comment: Prevent the attachments from "flexing" ? If you want it fixed, why are you using flex-grow/shrink on it?

Comment: bellow — same question in russian.

Comment: @onetrickpony I want it flex in some bounds in the way I want them to. Editor is main element of page, and if there are attached many files they can't have more then 148px of space in the page.

Comment: does the margin-bottom on header is your problem ? or even sides and bottom margins ? http://jsfiddle.net/7ADtq/2/

Comment: no, my problem is resizing of .attachment block without any connection to content of this block. I want .attachments have 0px height if there is no article tag inside and from 0 to 148px height depending of the count of article elements inside and .editor element get all other space.

Comment: Simply remove flex-grow and flex-shrink from it and its height will not exceed 148px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` on anything except for `flex-grow` on the `.editor`.

This way the fixed heights of footer and header wouldn't change, the height of the `.attachments` would be equal to its content but not bigger than its `max-height`, and the `.editor` would fill all other space.

- Here is an example without content at attachements — http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/r9b8E/ — it have the desired `0` height.
- Here is it with one line of text: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/z2Fj6/
- Here is it with 10 lines — http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/McZTV/

**Updated:** and if you'd need to have some min-height at `.editor`, you can just set it, but if you'd like other blocks not to shrink when the body becomes smaller, you should give everyone `flex-shrink: 0` — http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/X7L8S/ (resize the result pane to see how it behaves)